# Rendering ManyToMandyColumn as individual links to each related object

Tags: django-tables2

I have a **Unit** table that has a ManyToMany relationship with **Activities**.

When rendering the Activities in my Unit table, I want to have each Activity be a link to its own detail view.

I have tried many methods of doing so, but have not been able to figure out the best method.

I can get the URLs using a lambda:

`activities = tables.ManyToManyColumn(verbose_name='Activities', transform=lambda obj: obj.get_absolute_url,)`

But I can not find a good solution for actually *rendering* that link.

It seems like I should be able to customize the rendering of the link by accessing each item in a `render_activities()` method. But the value in `render_FOO()` methods when using `ManyToManyColumns` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `django-tables2==2.0.0a5`, `ManyToManyColumn` has a keyword argument `linkify_item`, which can be used like this:

```
activities = tables.ManyToManyColumn(verbose_name="Activities", linkify_item=True)
```

This will call `get_absolute_url()` for each related object in the `ManyRelatedManager`.

For pre-2.0 versions of django-tables2, you can use the `transform` keyword argument to create the `<a>`-tags like this:

```
activities = tables.ManyToManyColumn(
    verbose_name="Activities", 
    transform=lambda obj: '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(obj.get_absolute_url(), str(obj))
)
```

This slightly more verbose method also works in the 2.0.0 alpha versions.

Comment: Thanks @Jieter! Didn't realize I could render HTML like that.

Comment: After reading this again, you might have to use `format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', obj.get_absolute_url(), str(obj))` to make sure the html is not escaped.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a TemplateColumn to get it to work:

```
activities = tables.TemplateColumn(empty_values=(),
                                       orderable=False,
                                       template_code='''
                                        {% for activity in record.activities.all %}
                                            <a href="{% url "activity-detail" activity.pk %}">{{activity}}</a>, 
                                        {%endfor%}
                                        '''
                                       )
```